# How to use Internet Explorer OnQuit Event in a BHO using C#?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

I'm trying to use the OnQuit Event of IE, but it's just not firing when I close Internet Explorer. Is there any other way to detect closing of tabs, or the browser in IE?

I'm using it in a BHO written in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IE9 and native c++ BHO (ATL), I've no problems getting the onQuit event
My BHO derives from IDispEventImpl, and in the SINK_MAP I specify the DISPID_ONQUIT event:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMyBho
    :public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>
    ...
    ,IObjectWithSiteImpl<CMyBho>
    ,IDispEventImpl<1, CMyBho, &DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, &LIBID_SHDocVw, 1, 1>
{
    ...
    BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CMyBho)
        SINK_ENTRY_EX( 1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_ONQUIT, onQuit )
    END_SINK_MAP()
    ...
    STDMETHODCALLTYPE onQuit( );
    ...
    STDMETHOD(SetSite)(IUnknown* unkSite) {
        CComQIPtr<IServiceProvider> ifServiceProvider(unkSite);
        CComPtr<IWebBrowser2> ifBrz2;
        ifServiceProvider->QueryService( SID_SWebBrowserAPP, IID_IWebBrowser2,
                                         (void**)&ifBrz2 );
        this->DispEventAdvise( ifBrz2 );
    }
}
```

Saying all that, I know this is native code (vs. C#) and this is IE9 - but maybe it will give you a hint what needs to be done on your C# implementation. Sent me a note or comment if you want the full source code or need more help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [WebBrowser Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085.aspx) then as per this [OnQuit() MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136549.aspx):
**`The WebBrowser object ignores this event.`**. One solution is to use native code as mentioned in Uri's answer.

Answer (score 0):

OnQuit works pretty well for me with IE11.

Handler:

```
public void OnQuit() 
{
    logger.Debug("Entered OnQuit");
}
```

Wiring:

```
int IObjectWithSite.SetSite(object site)
{       
    if (site != null)
    {
        mainWindowBrowser = (WebBrowser)site;
        mainWindowBrowser.DocumentComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
        mainWindowBrowser.OnQuit += new DWebBrowserEvents2_OnQuitEventHandler(this.OnQuit);
    }
    else
    {
        mainWindowBrowser.DocumentComplete -= new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
        mainWindowBrowser.OnQuit -= new DWebBrowserEvents2_OnQuitEventHandler(this.OnQuit);
        mainWindowBrowser = null;
    }
    return 0;
}
```